# Can JaVers return a count of filtered entries?

Tags: java, javers

JaVers is a great library. I wonder, though, whether it offers a way of determining the number of results that would be returned by a JQL query.

This would be extremely helpful in our use case, which would be to:

1) Use JaVers’ skip() and limit() functions to return just a page of requested data.

2) Determine and return additional pagination-related data, such as whether the returned page is the last one and how many pages exist in the system (which depends on the user specified page size... along with the maximum number of possible results in the system - which I'm unsure of how best to retrieve).

I realize that we can simply load all results returned by JaVers' findChanges method into memory to get the full count. Is there a more efficient alternative, though?

Kind thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

There is no count() in JQL. It could be added in the future but the performance gain is not obvious.

In many cases, database count() queries are not significantly faster than select queries.
What could be saved, are network and application's CPU resources used for fetching snapshots from DB and JSON parsing.

Some tests should be created to estimate the performance gain comparing count(*) queries vs findChanges() queries.

Comment: It would be interesting to profile memory use of the two options as well. It seems as though relying on the DB to return count(*) would obviate the need to load records into the JVM and subsequently count them there. Even as-is, though, JaVers is great!

Comment: Thanks. Btw, this counting feature looks like a good candidate for contribution. Let me know, if you'd like to help developing JaVers.

Comment: I’d indeed like to help – JaVers is definitely a worthwhile project. It may be a while before I have the bandwidth, but I’ll touch base about contributing when able.

Comment: ok, find me on gitter chat when you will be ready https://gitter.im/javers/javers